# Can an object interact with other objects of its type

Tags: java, class, object

I am relatively new to java and am trying to make a card class for my blackjack game.  I am wondering if there is a way to make it aware of other Card objects that have already been created to check their card value and make sure I do not create a duplicate.  Any other tips to improve my code is also greatly appreciated.

```
class Card{
private int cardNum;
//1-4 ace 5-8 two 9-12 three 13-16 four 17-20 five 21-24 six 25-28 seven 29-32 eight 33-36 nine 
//37-40 ten 41-44 jack 45-48 queen 49-52 king
private int value;

public String toString(){
    return findCard() + " " + findSuit();
}

public Card(){
    cardNum = (int)(Math.random * 52)+1;
    giveValue();

}

public String findSuit(){
    if(cardNum % 4 == 1){
        return "of clubs";
    } else if(cardNum % 4 == 2){
        return "of diamonds";
    } else if(cardNum % 4 == 3){
        return "of hearts";
    } else {
        return "of spades";
    }
}
public void giveValue(){
    if(cardNum % 13 == 1){
        value = 11;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 2){
        value = 2;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 3){
        value = 3;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 4){
        value = 4;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 5){
        value = 5;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 6){
        value = 6;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 7){
        value = 7;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 8){
        value = 8;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 9){
        value = 9;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 10){
        value = 10;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 11){
        value = 10;
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 12){
        value = 10;
    } else {
        value = 10;
    }
}
public String findCard(){
    if(value == 11){
        return "ace";
    } else if(value == 2){
        return "two";
    } else if(value == 3){
        return "three";
    } else if(value == 4){
        return "four";
    } else if(value == 5){
        return "five";
    } else if(value == 6){
        return "six";
    } else if(value == 7){
        return "seven";
    } else if(value == 8){
        return "eight";
    } else if(value == 9){
        return "nine";
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 10){
        return "ten";
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 11{
        return "jack";
    } else if(cardNum % 13 == 12{
        return "queen";
    } else {
        reutrn "king";
    }
}
```

Comment: `giveValue()` does not work.  Try it with 1-4, 5-8, etc., as specified in your comment, and you'll see that the value doesn't match what your comment says it's supposed to be.  You will need `/`, not `%`.  I'm sure you can figure out the details.

Comment: To answer your question: I like saka1029's approach, which is a totally different approach.  But if you want to keep the approach you're working on but make sure the constructor doesn't use a duplicate value, consider using a `Set`.  I think it would make life easier to use `Set<Integer>` instead of `Set<Card>`; then when you generate a random number, check to see if the number is in the `Set<Integer>`.  You'll need a set that is shared by all `Card`s, which means you may want to pass in the `Set` as a constructor parameter.  That's just one possibility.

Comment: @ajb surprisingly, even though it does not match the comment, the method used generated 52 different cards. aces are 1, 14, 27, 40 (club, diamond, heart. spade), 2s are 2, 15, 28, 41 (diamond, heart, spade, club)...

Comment: @njzk2 I think that since 4 and 13 are relatively prime, that means that if (a mod 4) = (b mod 4) and (a mod 13) = (b mod 13), that implies (a mod 52) = (b mod 52).  That's why all the cards generated are unique.  There must be some number theory theorem about this.